# NetCore API error usuario windows DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-core, iis, entity-framework-core

Tengo una web MVC en .NET Core, esta web consume una API que es la que consulta mediante EF los datos de la base de datos. La conexión a la base de datos se hace mediante Seguridad Integrada. El problema que tengo es que al pasar las credenciales de la web a la API en el controlador me retorna correctamente el usuario que le he pasado, pero cuando el DbContext se conecta, lo hace con el usuario que ejecuta el IIS, que me falta para que funcione correctamente?

```
string APIUrl = "http://localhost:8001/api/values/GetUser";

HttpClientHandler ClientHdl = new HttpClientHandler();
//ClientHdl.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
ClientHdl.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"pppp\usuario1", "AAAAA");            

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(ClientHdl))
    {

        var oJson = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(APIUrl);
        JsonSerializerSettings serSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        serSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        List<string> oData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(oJson, serSettings);

        return "";
    }
Muchas gracias
```